# как правильно писать код, с пробелом или без между скобкой и названием метода?

Tags: code-style, style-guide

```
someFunction(){
  //some code
}
```

или

```
someFunction () {
  //some code
}
```

справедливо ли верное написание (пока я не знаю которое предпочтительнее) для всех языков?

Comment: а с какого конца надо разбивать яйцо?

Comment: Нету правильного варианта.

Comment: Хм.. Надо было хотя бы язык указать, а то у разных языков могут быть разные традиции.

Comment: Я в своей практике встречал только `somefunction() { ... }`, посему склонен считать, что обе эти записи не рекомендуются. Но это и неважно, т. к. этот вопрос нужно рассматривать в контексте конкретного проекта/сообщества/языка. Универсальных норм попросту нет. Поэтому уместнее сформулировать скорее как "имея синтаксически равнозначные записи, как выбрать, какой записью пользоваться"? Равнозначность важна, потому что мало ли, завтра кто-нибудь выпустит язык, где эти записи означают разные вещи.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно писать код, придерживаясь фиксированного стиля.

И тот, и другой вариант, и также вариант

```
someFunction()
{
    //some code
}
```

— все являются валидными стилями.

Вы должны выбрать стиль, который вам нравится, и придерживаться его. Или если вы пишете в команде, вы должны придерживаться стиля команды.

---

Исключение: некоторые языки предписывают определённый стиль. Например, Python предписывает лесенку, а Javascript — «египетские» скобки (из-за [semicolon insertion](https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/) приходится в *некоторых* случаях отказываться от открывающей скобки на новой строке, и для однородности стиля приходится так делать везде). Но это скорее исключение, чем правило.

---

Дополнение. Почему общий, однородный стиль важен? Дело в том, что код пишется не только для компилятора (ему-то как раз стиль безразличен), а для других программистов в вашей команде, для тех, кто будет разбираться в проекте и поддерживать его после вас. Неоднородный стиль снижает (в запущенных случаях сильно снижает) эффективность чтения и понимания вашего текста. Хуже того, вам самому через некоторое время, возможно, придётся читать ваш же код!

Пишите так, чтобы вам было приятно читать.

Comment: С появлением линтеров почти у каждого языка есть наиболее распространённый способ форматирования, который попадает в дефаултные настройки.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Скорее у каждого компилятора :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тем не менее, посмотрите на http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,774 и http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,793

Comment: @VladD, js вроде ничего не предписывает, а в питоне вроде как скобок вообще нет, там же отступами все

Comment: @Grundy: https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/

Comment: @VladD эту ссылку стоит добавить в ответ (понятно, что к функциям она отношения не имеет, но именно из-за этого js приянто ставить скобки именно так + из соображений одинаковости для всех конструкций)

Comment: @PashaPash: Я бы добавил сразу, будь вопрос по js, а не language agnostic.

Comment: @VladD ну как-то странно ответить на часть "справедливо ли верное написание (пока я не знаю которое предпочтительнее) для всех языков?" - "нет", но не сказать, почему именно нет. Ведь, строго говоря, Javascript не предписывает египетские скобки (тем более для объявлении функций). Просто он ведет себя неожиданно в одном конкретном случае.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну, это вытекает из (подразумеваемого) правила о консистентности стиля.

Comment: @VladD, ну не, это ж к скобкам функций и блоков не имеет отношешия жешь :)

Comment: @Grundy: Так однородность стиля же! Специально написал «и для однородности стиля приходится так делать везде».

Answer (score 1):

В javascript'е сейчас принято писать без пробела перед круглой скобкой и с пробелом перед фигурной:

```
var x = {
  method() {
    return 7;
  }
}

function soSmth(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}
```

Пробел перед скобкой ставится только с управляющими конструкциями:

```
if (true) {
}

function () { // анонимная функция
}

do {
} while (false)
```

На вопрос "почему" ответа, конечно, нет, поскольку это чисто стилистика и на функциональность не влияет.

PS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Comment: Будучи модератором Вы бы переоткрыли этот вопрос? :) Отвечайте, пока я ещё могу переголосовать.

Comment: есть вполне конкретная причина, по которой JS принято писать именно так - это Automatic Semicolon Insertion. Т.е. для JS в общем случае есть разница, на той же строчке написана {, или на новой.

Comment: @PashaPash, эта причина относится только к расположению фигурных скобок, но не к порбелам. Пробелы ни на что не влияют, только переводы строк.

Comment: @alexolut, в вопросе не указан язык, поэтому он слишком общий. Даже сейчас моего голоса за переоткрытие на нём нет.

Comment: Зачем же тогда было на него давать ответ?